# How to get last 5 games of a team out of my access database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Hi all below you see a screenshot of my database:

[image]

But now I want to be able to make a table that calculates every players last 5 games. As I'm totaly new to access db I really have no clue how to do this.

Can you guys help me a hand with this one?

When I use the 2nd snippet in the answer below I get these:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are SQL routes according to your data. To use in MS Access simply create a new query under Create Tab on Ribbon and place the below SQL in the SQL view of a new created query. You may need to adjust query according to your actual table names and/or fields.

**SAME GAMES FOR ALL PLAYERS**

Assuming every player shares the same last five games, you could run an aggregate query across all players, using a subquery in `INNER JOIN` clause to calculate last five game dates. Do note: subquery, `LastFiveDates` can be saved as its own query and used directly in `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT [LookUp to Players],
       Sum(GamesWon) As SumOfGamesWon, Sum(GamesLost) As SumOfGamesLost, 
       Sum(OwnOdds) As SumOfOwnOdds, Sum(OppOdds) As SumOfOppOdds, 
       Sum(GamesPlayed) As SumOfGamesPlayed
FROM GamesTable
INNER JOIN 
       (
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 [Date] 
        FROM GamesTable 
        ORDER BY [Date] DESC
       ) As LastFiveDates           
ON GamesTable.[Date] = LastFiveDates.[Date]
GROUP BY [LookUp to Players];
```

**DIFFERING GAMES FOR EACH PLAYER**

*SIMPLE SELECT APPROACH*

Now, if players differ in their last five games, you have to join on different queries or union queries. Again, the below uses a subquery in an inner join but you can save that `LastFiveGames` as its own stored query and join in `INNER JOIN` line.

```
SELECT GamesTable.[LookUp to Players],
       Sum(GamesWon) As SumOfGamesWon, Sum(GamesLost) As SumOfGamesLost, 
       Sum(OwnOdds) As SumOfOwnOdds, Sum(OppOdds) As SumOfOppOdds, 
       Sum(GamesPlayed) As SumOfGamesPlayed
FROM GamesTable
INNER JOIN 
       (
        SELECT [Lookup to Players], [Date],
              (SELECT Count(*) 
               FROM GamesTable t2 
               WHERE GamesTable.[Date] <= t2.[Date] 
               AND   GamesTable.[Lookup to Players] = t2.[Lookup to Players]) AS GameOrder
        FROM GamesTable
       ) As LastFiveDates        
ON GamesTable.[Date] = LastFiveDates.[Date]
AND GamesTable.[Lookup to Players] = LastFiveDates.[Lookup to Players]
WHERE LastFiveDates.GameOrder <= 5
GROUP BY GamesTable.[LookUp to Players];
```

**DIFFERING GAMES FOR EACH PLAYER**

*VBA CREATE TABLE APPROACH*

Due to performance issues of Access running the query as a stored query, VBA can re-create the GamesStats iteratively looping through all distinct players using the very first query condition for player.

```
Public Function GameTableStats()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim tbldef As TableDef, rst As Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String, i As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT PlayerName FROM GamesTable", dbOpenDynaset)

    For Each tbldef In db.TableDefs
        If tbldef.Name = "GamesStats" Then
            db.Execute "DROP TABLE [GamesStats]", dbFailOnError
        End If
    Next tbldef

    rst.MoveLast
    rst.MoveFirst

    i = 1
    Do While Not rst.EOF

        If i = 1 Then
            ' FIRST PLAYER (MAKE-TABLE QUERY) '
            strSQL = "SELECT GamesTable.[PlayerName]," _
                        & "       Sum(GamesWon) As SumOfGamesWon, Sum(GamesLost) As SumOfGamesLost," _
                        & "       Sum(OwnOdds) As SumOfOwnOdds, Sum(OppOdds) As SumOfOppOdds," _
                        & "       Sum(GamePlayed) As SumOfGamePlayed" _
                        & " INTO GamesStats" _
                        & " FROM GamesTable" _
                        & " INNER JOIN" _
                        & "       (" _
                        & "        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 [Date], [PlayerName]" _
                        & "        FROM GamesTable" _
                        & "        WHERE [PlayerName]=""" & rst!PlayerName & """" _
                        & "        ORDER BY [Date] DESC" _
                        & "       ) As LastFiveDates" _
                        & " ON GamesTable.[Date] = LastFiveDates.[Date]" _
                        & " WHERE GamesTable.[PlayerName]= """ & rst!PlayerName & """" _
                        & " GROUP BY GamesTable.[PlayerName];"
        Else
            ' ALL OTHER PLAYERS (INSERT APPEND QUERIES) '
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO GamesStats ([PlayerName], [SumOfGamesWon], [SumOfGamesLost]," _
                        & "                    [SumOfOwnOdds], [SumOfOppOdds], [SumOfGamePlayed])" _
                        & " SELECT GamesTable.[PlayerName], " _
                        & "       Sum(GamesWon) As SumOfGamesWon, Sum(GamesLost) As SumOfGamesLost, " _
                        & "       Sum(OwnOdds) As SumOfOwnOdds, Sum(OppOdds) As SumOfOppOdds,  " _
                        & "       Sum(GamePlayed) As SumOfGamePlayed " _
                        & " FROM GamesTable " _
                        & " INNER JOIN  " _
                        & "       ( " _
                        & "        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 [Date], [PlayerName]  " _
                        & "        FROM GamesTable  " _
                        & "        WHERE [PlayerName]=""" & rst!PlayerName & """" _
                        & "        ORDER BY [Date] DESC" _
                        & "       ) As LastFiveDates " _
                        & " ON GamesTable.[Date] = LastFiveDates.[Date]" _
                        & " WHERE GamesTable.[PlayerName]= """ & rst!PlayerName & """" _
                        & " GROUP BY GamesTable.[PlayerName];"
        End If

        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        i = i + 1
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    MsgBox "Successfully created GamesStats table!", vbInformation

End Function
```

Comment: I tried to use the middle one but I get a syntax error in this part:   (SELECT Count(*) 
               FROM Table2 t2 
               WHERETable2.[Date] <= t2.[Date] 
               AND   Table2.[Lookup to Players] = t2.[Lookup to Players]) AS GameOrder

Comment: OK Fixed this but now it asks for parameter values.

Comment: Please take a look at the screenshot above. I use the 2nd snippet you posted. But get those parameter values boxes.

Comment: The 2nd query doens't run . Don't know what the problem is but access keeps running on it

Comment: is it a problem  that not every player played 5 games?

Comment: so I click run and nothing happens. Access just "freezes" till i press esc. There are no errors coming up.

Comment: I changed everything just like your example. No paramters are asked but nothing happens...

Comment: I opened it again but still status bar stays at running query. 

My table is simple: ( name of table: GamesTable )

PlayerName, GamesWon, GamesLost, OwnOdds and OppOdds are my columns

Comment: sorry forgot that date is also included in my table :)

Comment: SELECT GamesTable.[PlayerName], Sum(GamesWon) AS   SumOfGamesWon, Sum(GamesLost) AS SumOfGamesLost, Sum(OwnOdds) AS SumOfOwnOdds, Sum(OppOdds) AS SumOfOppOdds
FROM GamesTable INNER JOIN (SELECT [PlayerName], [Date], (SELECT Count(*)                 FROM GamesTable t2                 WHERE GamesTable.[Date] <= t2.[Date]                 AND   GamesTable.[PlayerName] = t2.[PlayerName]) AS GameOrder FROM GamesTable)  AS LastFiveDates ON (GamesTable.[Date] = LastFiveDates.[Date]) AND (GamesTable.[PlayerName] = LastFiveDates.[PlayerName])
WHERE LastFiveDates.GameOrder <= 5
GROUP BY

Comment: that's the query i use followed by group by GamesTable.[PlayerName]; ( last post had reached max caracters

Comment: i use ms acces 2010, windows 10, SSD 250 GB and on wireless network with rather low speed at the moment

Comment: I'm at my local machine. Btw I also have 16gb RAM

Comment: can you paste the exact query you are using?

Comment: so         SELECT [PlayerName], [Date],
              (SELECT Count(*) 
               FROM GamesTable gt 
               WHERE GamesTable.[Date] <= gt.[Date] 
               AND   GamesTable.[PlayerName] = gt.[PlayerName]) AS GameOrder
        FROM GamesTable
       ) 

In a seperate query?

Comment: SELECT [PlayerName], [Date],
              SELECT Count(*) 
               FROM GamesTable 
               WHERE GamesTable.[Date] <= GamesTable.[Date] 
               AND   GamesTable.[PlayerName] = GamesTable.[PlayerName]) AS GameOrder
        FROM GamesTable

so this in a seperate query and save it as LastFiveDates

Comment: I run LastFiveDates seperatly and I get a table with all players names and next to it the number of matches they played. And a date but don't know what that date does...

Comment: Please send me the file (remove irrelevant tables) via a Dropbox, Google Drive, or OneDrive link.

Comment: Just checked your initial table screen shot and noticed `OwnOdds` and `OppOdds` uses commas to separate decimal points. US English which I use uses the dot separator for decimal points. See [map](http://www.statisticalconsultants.co.nz/blog/how-the-world-separates-its-decimals.html). So your table would render as string variables and so `Sum()` in query may not work. Make sure the language setting of your machine is set to one that uses commas and not points as Access will adjust accordingly.

Comment: you can find the file in here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uud9fiq0awrcmel/GamesTable.accdb?dl=0

Comment: Thanks, I did re-create you issue with Access hanging. Turns out it's a performance issue. Your data is simply too large for Access to handle (which maintains a 2GB memory limit) as players have up to 70 games so the `LastFiveDates` is quite an involved subquery. My test example had just 6 players with 6 games each. However, I did import your table in SQL Server and query ran in one second! Either let Access finish processing as you go for a cup of coffee or upsize to a server level database.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort and help!

Comment: All's not lost. Access VBA can help. See above edit where I add a function that re-creates the `GamesStats` table each time it runs, basically looping through each distinct player and passing `PlayerName` as the filter condition. We bypass the `LastFiveDates` subquery. Call the function behind a form button, trigger event, or on its own in the VBA IDE area. Do be patient. It takes about 30 seconds.

Comment: So I can use access. And the edit you posted I should add to vba in access and not in a query?

Comment: I've ran the vba script and +I get the message" created succesfully". Should I now use a query to get my last 5 games?

Comment: so to get my gamesstat table updated i only need to run this edit you posted?

Comment: Little question left :)
What If I would arrange my table as:

ID - HomePlayer - AwayPlayer - HomeGamesWon - AwayGamesWon - HomeOdds - AwayOdds

What would the code look like than if I want a table with SumofGamesWon for last 5 games - SumofGamesLost for last 5 games - SumofOwnOdds for last 5 games - SumofOppOdds for last 5 games

And this per team.

In this case you have to look in 2 columns for the teams to calculate their games won and lost and their own odds and opp odds.

Can you make adjustments to get sth like this?

Comment: Simple change, just add the Sums together in aggregate queries: `Sum(HomeGamesWon) + Sum(AwayGamesWon) As SumofGamesWon`...

Comment: so i would also be ablo to make a ranking than with sth like if HomePlayerGamesWon > AwayPlayerGamesWon than homePlayer 3 points or sth lik that

Comment: I've copied the code to make a Last 10 Last 15 and Last 20 match lookup. But for a player I got 2 Games(when i look at last 5), 2 games when I look at LAst 10, 4 games when i look at last 15 and and 3 games when i look at last 20